# Route guard not working when returning true

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a route guard like this. It gets the number of orgs for a user from the db, and checks if that user is still active within the org, then returns true. In the console, `userIsAffiliatedWithOrg.isActive` is returning true, yet I'm still being redirected to `/` instead of to the proper route. Any ideas on where my code is wrong?

```
export class OrgDashboardGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private orgusers: OrgUserService){}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.orgusers.getListOfNPOsForUser(this.auth.getUserId())
      .subscribe(
        (result: any) => {
          if (result && result.organizations.length >= 1) {
            // check if the user is active for the org dashboard attempting to be accessed
            var userIsAffiliatedWithOrg = result.organizations.find(x => x.id === parseInt(route.params["id"]));
            if (userIsAffiliatedWithOrg === undefined) {
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
              return false;
            } else {
              console.log('before checking active')
              console.log(userIsAffiliatedWithOrg)
              if (userIsAffiliatedWithOrg.isActive) {
                console.log('after active ' + userIsAffiliatedWithOrg.isActive)
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            }
          } else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
            return false;
          }
        },
        (err: any) => {
          console.log(err);
          return false;
        }
      )
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: why you have navigateByUrl just before return false in end of that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `canActivate` returns nothing. In your case, your `canActivate` should return observable.

Try this.

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return new Observable<boolean | UrlTree>( observer => {
      this.orgusers.getListOfNPOsForUser(this.auth.getUserId())
        .subscribe(
          (result: any) => {
            if (result && result.organizations.length >= 1) {
              // check if the user is active for the org dashboard attempting to be accessed
              var userIsAffiliatedWithOrg = result.organizations.find(x => x.id === parseInt(route.params["id"]));
              if (userIsAffiliatedWithOrg === undefined) {
                observer.next(this.router.parseUrl('/'));
              } else {
                console.log('before checking active');
                console.log(userIsAffiliatedWithOrg);
                if (userIsAffiliatedWithOrg.isActive) {
                  console.log('after active ' + userIsAffiliatedWithOrg.isActive);
                  observer.next(true);
                  return;
                }
                observer.next(false);
                return;
              }
            } else {
              observer.next(this.router.parseUrl('/'));
            }
          },
          (err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
            observer.next(false);
          }
        );
    });
  }
```

Comment: makes sense. I forgot about the observable part.